# XPath for labeled data?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I want to read the data which is inside the second `div`:

```
<div class="my-3">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">Monthly:</div>
  <div>0 / 30,000</div>
</div>
```

In the above markup, I want to read the `div` which contains the string: `0 / 30,000`

I was able to navigate to the first `div` which contains the string `"Monthly:"` with this XPath:

```
//*[normalize-space()='Monthly:']
```

How can I select the second `div` below after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
//*[normalize-space()='Monthly:']/following-sibling::div
```

Comment: While this works in OP's markup as currently presented, it could fail for several sorts of variations.  It's too much to fit into a comment, so I've explained some of the limitations and provided a more robust XPath in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77914002/290085).

Answer (score 0):

### Limitations of currently accepted answer

The XPath in the currently accepted answer,

```
//*[normalize-space()='Monthly:']/following-sibling::div
```

works for OP's exact case where there is a single `div` following the targeted label,

```
<div class="my-3">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">Monthly:</div>
  <div>0 / 30,000</div>
</div>
```

but can produce different results if there are multiple `div` sibling elements following the target.

For example, consider this markup:

```
<div class="my-3">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">Monthly:</div>
  <div>0 / 30,000</div>
  <div>more</div>
  <div>and more</div>
</div>
```

In this case, it won't just be `<div>0 / 30,000</div>` that's selected, but

```
  <div>0 / 30,000</div>
  <div>more</div>
  <div>and more</div>
```

### More robust XPath for labeled data

To select ***only the immediately following `div` element***, use this XPath instead:

```
//*[normalize-space()='Monthly:']/following-sibling::*[1][self::div]
```

To select ***only the immediately following element of any name***:

```
//*[normalize-space()='Monthly:']/following-sibling::*[1]
```